# JAVA Interactive brokers api

Tags: java, api, interactive-brokers

I call interactive broker `reqHistoricalData()` method and I see on IBGateaway i see that i get an error

> 200 | No security definition has been found for the request

I've tried to change sec type to different ones but always returns same result here's my code :

```
 public class IBrokersApi implements EWrapper {

private EClientSocket clientSocket = new EClientSocket(this);
public Contract contract = new Contract();

public void connect(){
    if(!clientSocket.isConnected()){
        clientSocket.eConnect("", 4002, 0);
    }
}

public void disconnect(){
    if(clientSocket.isConnected()){
        clientSocket.eDisconnect();
    }
}
public void getHistData(){
    contract.m_conId = 1;
    contract.m_symbol = "APPL"; // "ESJ13-FUT-GLOBEX";
    contract.m_secType = "STK";
    contract.m_exchange = "SMART";
    clientSocket.reqHistoricalData(0, contract,"20161120 00:00:00", "1 D", "1 day", "TRADES", 0, 2, null);
}
```

Comment: Code 200 usually means "success"

Comment: In Interactive brokers api it means not success.

Comment: So wouldn't that depend on the server configuration? Have you contacted the server admin? That is the place to start.

Comment: I agree with Jim. Also `contractId` field should be left blank.

Comment: You mean create a ticket for support or there is other way i could contact admin ?

Comment: no conid  like has been said and also AAPL, 2 As not 2 Ps.  The server code @JimGarrison mentioned has to do with HTTP and not the IB API.

Answer (score 1):

Your conId of "1" is incorrect.  AAPL stock happens to have a conId of 265598, which you can lookup using the ContractDetails mechanism in the API.

For most situations in IB API, you generally can choose to send in a conId and an exchange, or in a simple case like your example, you can specify a variety of "human readable" fields instead.  In your case, simply do not set the conId and do set the currency (which might be set by default).  So for creating a contract, your code should look like this:

```
    Contract c = new Contract();

    c.symbol("AAPL");
    c.secType(SecType.STK);
    c.exchange("SMART");
    c.currency("USD");
```

or for an option contract:

```
    Contract c = new Contract();

    c.symbol("AAPL");
    c.secType(SecType.OPT);
    c.exchange("SMART");
    c.currency("USD");      
    c.multiplier("100");                        // 1 option is for 100 stock shares
    c.lastTradeDateOrContractMonth("20180119"); // yyyyMMdd
    c.strike(175.00);
    c.right(Right.Put);                         // CALL or PUT
```